# healthy-wise: which keyboard is better?

Tags: keyboard, peripheral

there is a apple wireless keyboard and the apple keyboard with numeric keypad.

Which one is better for the overall healthy of my wrists and arms? I suffer from RSI and I want to buy a wireless keyboard but I'm afraid it will injure me.

Comment: I have a wired one with the 10-key pad - but that's actually because I like a 10-key. Of the half dozen keyboard types in the building, I find it the best to type on, by far… but, the only difference to the wireless keyboard is the 10-key itself, so if you are struggling with a clacky old windows-type keyboard, either will be a great improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend getting a natural ergonomic keyboard. Here is a link that Microsoft has explaining the difference. 
[Ergonomic Keyboards](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/ergonomic-keyboards)

There are numerous keyboards that are ergonomic. Microsoft and Logitech have a few that work with Mac's.